# special/accented characters not recognized correctly in java controller?

Tags: java, json, ajax, string, utf-8

I am sending stringified json from my ajax call to a java controller. 
My controller looks like `public TxnStatus setGlobalizationKeyChanges(@PathVariable String locale,@RequestBody String stringyfiedMap) throws Exception { }` but some of the special/accented characters dosent look same when I print or use stringyfiedMap.

I know that this is happening because I am catching the data in `java.lang.String` which is losing the meaning of original accented chars. So how can I handel the data as it is sent and perform my operations normally?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is introduced in all major Tomcat releases:

- 7.0.76, 8.0.42, 8.5.12

  You can define property requestTargetAllow to allow forbiden characters.
  Add this line in your catalina.properties

> tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{}